# Replacing username with profile link javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string where there are a bunch of usernames like this -

```
var someString = "@earth @moon";
```

And I want the string to be like this -

```
"[@earth](https://www.somewebsite.com/earth) [@moon](https://www.somewebsite.com/moon)"
```

I have thought of using regex expressions, but I am not really good in regex

```
console.log(myStr.replace(/[a-z0-9A-Z-_]/, 
  "[" + /[a-z0-9A-Z-_]/ +"](https://www.website.com/" + /[a-z0-9A-Z-_]/ 
);
```

How to do it?

Comment: I got stuck in making the regex expression, that is why I am in Stack Overflow

Comment: @FahemMoz and those regular expressions that you made are...?

Comment: It was something like this, I am getting a compiler error console.log(myStr.replace((@[a-z0-9A-Z-_])\w), "[" + (@[a-z0-9A-Z-_])\w +"](https://www.website.com/" + (@[a-z0-9A-Z-_])\w )

Comment: Code goes in your question, not in the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you always have the same pattern separated by whitespace, you don't need much of a regex, just split on space and replace the `@`:

```js
var someString = "@earth @moon";

var str = someString.split(/\s+/).map(item =>
  `[${item}](https://www.somewebsite.com/${item.replace('@', '')})`)
  .join(" ")

console.log(str)
```